# how to run multiple Api from test runner which multiple set of data

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

i have mutiple Apis , each api will use onetest data from data sheet and execute it.is it possible to check this scenario in postman.

suppose i have Api a' api b aoi c
api a will read first row data from excel' api b will read second row data etc

Comment: You could create a single request and have multiple data files. Each data file includes the API and data that you want to use in a single row. Export your collection and use the newman cli to execute the collection and attach the data file. You will have to run newman multiple times with each file. 

https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, however, an alternative solution would be to create a single request derived from data file variable and build multiple data files for each of your APIs.

Export your collection and use the newman cli to execute the collection and attach the data file. You will have to run newman multiple times with each file. like this

```
newman run "my.exported.postman_collection.json" -r "cli,html,json,junit" -n 1 --iteration-data "d:\my.first.file.csv"
newman run "my.exported.postman_collection.json" -r "cli,html,json,junit" -n 1 --iteration-data "d:\my.second.file.csv"
newman run "my.exported.postman_collection.json" -r "cli,html,json,junit" -n 1 --iteration-data "d:\my.third.file.csv"
```

More information on newman cli: https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/